# jQuery setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a jQuery function that flips an element and then turn it back after a few seconds, however there is multiple elements with the same "flip" tag and the setInterval elements flip all the elements back after the first click. How could i implement the flip effect to turn only the elements that have been clicked in e kind of flow, so that not all elements flip after the delay. The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.click').toggle(function() //on click functions => toggle elements
    {           

        setTimeout( function() { // trigger the flip-back after delay (1500ms)
        $('.flip').trigger('click');
        }, 1500) 

        $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('flip');
        $this.children('.front').delay(600).hide(0);
        $this.children('.back').delay(600).show(0);

    },          
        function() 
        {

        $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('flip');
        $this.children('.front').delay(600).show(0);
        $this.children('.back').delay(600).hide(0);

        });  
});
```

My intention is that the elements would flip back after the delay, but now all the clicked elements flip back after the delay, even though they are only visible for the time - delay. Hops this makes sense :)

Thnx for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, `$(this)` or `this` to refer the current item that is click. **Also**, the extra function is not needed, just use `toggleClass()` to apply/remove the class.

```
$('.click').click(function() //on click functions => toggle elements
{           

    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout( function() { // trigger the flip-back after delay (1500ms)
        $this.trigger('click');
    }, 1500);

    $this.toggleClass('flip');
    $this.children('.front').delay(600).hide(0);
    $this.children('.back').delay(600).show(0);

});
```

Comment: Shouldnt we use `var $this= $(this)` ? Why making it global ? Also, shouldnt the opening braces be placed in the same line ?

Comment: Thanks alot! However my intention (badly explained) was that the elements that has been clicked (and turned via css transitions to show a picture) turn back after the delay, but when you click multiple elements they all turn back after the delay at the same time. My purpose was to make each element visible / not visible fot the same amount of delay. (in other words no matter what you click the delaytime is always same for each element)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get it, but should'nt this do the same:

```
$('.click').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('flip').children('.front, .back')
           .delay(600).toggle(0).delay(1500).toggle(0, function() {
               $(this).parent().removeClass('flip');
           });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VCGbF/8/)